# Ninject with MVC - how can I manually get object from ninject inside controller method?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, dependency-injection, ninject

What I mean is - when I user Ninject for my controllers it automatically injects all fields to the controller constructor, now... I have class called CommonMethods in my project, and I need to pass certain fields from the controller to that class in order to use it (this class contains non-static methods only, so it needs to be created), of course I can do it by hand like this:

```
CommonMethods cm = new CommonMethods(someVarFromCurrentcontroller, someTherVar,... and so on..);
cm.SomeMethod();
```

However the above will force me to manually update the code, every time I modify "CommonMethods" constructor, so the question is - is there any way to use Ninject here? I would like to do something like:

```
IKernel k = new StandardKernel();
CommonMethods c = k.Get<CommonMethods>();
```

But if I try the above a get errors saying "No matching bindings are available for X" (but they are there). I guess this is because I use new kernel and not the one that is used on app startup. How can I resolve this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Best regards.

Edit 1:

This is how my controllers constructors look like:

```
private EFDbContext context;

private ISaleActionRepository saleActionRepository;
private IUserRepository userRepository;

public TestController(ISaleActionRepository saleActionRepository, IUserRepository userRepository, EFDbContext context)
{
    this.saleActionRepository = saleActionRepository;
    this.userRepository = userRepository;

    this.context = context;
}
```

And this is how my CommonMethods controller look like:

```
private IUserRepository userRepository;
private IPaymentRepository paymentRepository;
private IFunctionalityPackageRepository functionalityPackageRepository;
private ISettingRepository settingRepository;

public CommonMethods(IUserRepository userRepository, IPaymentRepository paymentRepository, IFunctionalityPackageRepository functionalityPackageRepository, ISettingRepository settingRepository)
{
    this.userRepository = userRepository;
    this.paymentRepository = paymentRepository;
    this.functionalityPackageRepository = functionalityPackageRepository;
    this.settingRepository = settingRepository;
}
```

Comment: It seems that your `CommonMethods` class is supplied with runtime values. Your DI container should only be responsible of building up object graphs by using compile dependencies and configuration values. So its best to NOT resolve that CommonMethods class from the kernel.

Comment: @Steven:

I must say I don't understand - please see my edit, I added some code to show how constructors look like in both MVC controller classes and in my CommonMethods class, as You can see - the are practically identical, why is it good to use Ninject for controllers, but bad for other classes? Please explain.

Comment: Ahh, I see. Just inject `CommonMethods` into the `TestController`'s constructor. You should let the container build up the object graph all the way.

Comment: @Steven:

That did the trick, thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add the `CommonMethods` service as argument in your `TestController`'s constructor and let the container build up the complete object graph. Such object graph can be many layers deep.

```
private readonly EFDbContext context;
private readonly ISaleActionRepository saleActionRepository;
private readonly IUserRepository userRepository;
private readonly CommonMethods commonMethods;

public TestController(ISaleActionRepository saleActionRepository, 
    IUserRepository userRepository, EFDbContext context, CommonMethods commonMethods)
{
    this.saleActionRepository = saleActionRepository;
    this.userRepository = userRepository;
    this.context = context;
    this.commonMethods = commonMethods;
}
```